# A question about gradient field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $\vec{F}=(xy,x^2+y^2)$ be a vector field. 
Is there exist a function $f(x,y)$ such that $\vec{\nabla}f=\vec{F}$?

My attempt: if $f_x=xy$ and $f_y=x^2+y^2$, then $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{2}+g(y)$. Therefore $f_y=\frac{x^2}{2}+g'(y)$. Hence $\frac{x^2}{2}+g'(y)=x^2+y^2$, so $g'(y)=\frac{x^2}{2}+y^2$. But $g(y)$ is a function of $y$,  a contradiction.

On the other hand, if you take any circle $C(t)=(R\cos t,R\sin t)$, $t\in[0,2\pi]$ then 
$$
\oint_{C}f\cdot d\vec{l}=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(R^2\cos t\sin t,R^2)\cdot(-R\sin t,R\cos t)\,dt=R^3\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^3t\,dt=0
$$
 Why this does not contradict the first claim? Thanks

Comment: That's right. Your contradiction proves, that there isn't such a function $f$.

Comment: Thanks, but if you take any circle around $(0,0)$, the line integral over this circle is 0. See my edit.

Comment: The theorem is that if there exist F(x, y) is such that $f(x,y)= \nabla F$ then the integral around any closed path of f(x,y) is 0.  It does **not** say if f is not an "exact differential" that the integral around some closed path may not be 0.  It is the difference between "if A then B" and "if B then A".  One does not imply the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the line integral being zero even if the field is non-conservative.  It works in your case since the circular path is symmetric about the y-axis and the curl of the field is odd with respect to x.  Pick a path that does not have that symmetric, for example the unit square in the first quadrant, and you will get a non-zero answer.
By Stoke Theorem, you get the work as
$$W=\int \nabla \times F dA$$
$$=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x dydx$$
$$=1/2$$